# Can you configure the sample length for mod_status requests per second?

Tags: apache

The Apache Module mod_status allows you to view the current average requests per second being served.  It measures this average over a fairly long period of time however (I don't know exactly how long).  Is it possible to modify this length to something shorter so that I can get a more accurate idea of the current load on the server?

Answer (score 1):

you can count the average by yourself.

write a script(such as python) to get the server-status with parameter `?refresh=1&auto`, and then accumulate the BusyWorkers, which is the current request number.